# Pass value to variable in executing SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package to loading some data based on the month and I want to call the package via windows batch file. Here is what's in the cmd file which is working fine now:

```
CD /D C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn

DTExec.exe /f "E:\APAutomation\SSIS\AP\ActualDataImport_Console_PL.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[User::ActualMonth].Properties[Value]; "9"
```

Now I replace the 9 with a variable so to make it less hardcoded

```
CD /D C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
set ActualMonth = 9

DTExec.exe /f "E:\APAutomation\SSIS\AP\ActualDataImport_Console_PL.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[User::ActualMonth].Properties[Value]; "%ActualMonth%"
```

however, this won't work: this is the error msg:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn>DTExec.exe /f "E:\APAutomatio
n\SSIS\AP\ActualDataImport_Console_PL.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[User::Actual
Month].Properties[Value]; ""
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Argument ""\Package.Variables[User::ActualMonth].Properties[Value];"" for option
 "set" is not valid.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I also tried:

```
set ActualMonth = "9"
DTExec.exe /f "E:\APAutomation\SSIS\AP\ActualDataImport_Console_PL.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[User::ActualMonth].Properties[Value]; %ActualMonth%
```

it threw me the same error msg. Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your specific problem is the spaces...

use this

```
set ActualMonth=9
```

instead of this:

```
set ActualMonth = 9
```

What you're doing is basically setting a package config from a batch file. It might work better if you set up the package to read from a package config file and put your month number in there.

Comment: I suggest you look into package configurations... are you going to set this month manually every time?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Actually in my real package, I am calling the setenviroment bat file, which is the value of parameters. which I didn't mention in order to simply and focus the question i am asking here.